# using swipe gesture recognizer swipe from one viewcontroller to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Swipe-Right

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(slideToRightWithGestureRecognizer:)];
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
```

Swipe-Left

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(slideToLeftWithGestureRecognizer:)];
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
```

On '`slideToRightWithGestureRecognizer`' method i want to write code which opens abcViewController which has a viewcontroller on storyboard and same with '`slideToLeftWithGestureRecognizer`' to open xyzViewController which also has view controller on storyboard. Without using Navigation View Controller in the program

Comment: Do you have those viewControllers connected on your storyboard or do they have an ID? Show us your setup

Comment: @Daniel I have given them storyboard id

Answer (score 1):

Should be very easy to accomplish:

When the ViewControllers are connected on your storyboard you could easily do it like this:

```
- (void)slideToLeftWithGestureRecognizer:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myConnectionIdentifierHere"]
}
```

If not:

```
- (void)slideToLeftWithGestureRecognizer:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"myStoryboardName" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewControllerIdentifierHere"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `UIPageViewController`? Or does it necessarily have to be a swipe and not a pan gesture (UIPageViewController provides navigation between view controllers using a pan gesture interactively).

Comment: Actually it currently implemented through pageviewContoller, it uses buttons and when we hold and drag them it moves, so there are button on left and right side on each of the viewcontoller(three view controller). My task is to remove the button and when user swipes left it goes to leftviewController and when user swipes right it goes to rightViewController